# Force PHP to wait till another request is completed?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

My php script reads a user-specified CSV URL and write the data to a mysql database and the user can see his data on the web GUI. The fields of the table will be dropped with a new request.
This works very good – but:

If 2 (or more) user request their own CSV URL at the same time, sometimes they get not their own data (they get data of the table from the process before).  Is there a way to set user to “wait” or “pending” till another request is completed?

Hope you get it. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like your program is holding data for too long causing read locks. Both your database and software infrastructure needs to be changed to work with data more sufficiently. Ie, ensuring that the data is **unique** to that user and not holding onto the data for too long. Rightfully so what @GordonM mentioned - its important to *cross-reference* tables!

Comment: If each request gets a unique identifier then you can have multiple concurrent requests that don't overwrite each other.  This could be done by having a Request table with an autoincrementing ID that gets created at the start of the request and a requestData table for each item in the CSV to be processed with an additional column holding the ID in the request table generated for that request.

Comment: Not enough information! We would have to see some code before we could give a decent answer.
This can be caused by so many variables, one just can't cover everything in one answer.

Comment: Is this a shared table? Is that where the contention is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your app uses Apache and mod_php, which is a common but not the only way. When a new HTTP request is made of Apache, it spawns a new PHP process to action the request. That new PHP process must do everything needed, and when it has done so, PHP terminates.

If I understand you, you have a form that submits a URL (text field); when PHP runs that URL is fetched within php and the contents put in a database. The database is then rendered into html and returned as the form result -- or something like that. And when two people do this at the same time, things get mixed up because they're both using the same table names.

If I've understood properly, the application needs to either:

- use table names prefixed by something specific to the user - e.g. their login name, or something similar.
- use some locking mechanism on the server, such that a 'one-at-a-time' queue is enforced. I think this is what you asked about...

I am not sure of the point of this -- whether this is a learning exercise, or something else, but avoid one-at-a-time as a solutiuon: it's not easy to make it work right and is not the way the web 'works' overall.

Using table name prefixes would go something like:

- decide on a method to distinguish each user: perhaps you can use a table with an autoincrement row id, and the row id is used? Perhaps you have session logins and can use a login name. Ensure that only 'simple' characters are in the id used for tables: e.g. filter out all but ASCII letters and digits with preg_replace().
- Where you were creating a table with a constant name, add the new 'id' to that:

  ```
  $sql = "create table csv (" . $fields . ")";
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
  $sql = "create table csv" . $id . " (" . $fields . ")";
  ```

You probably find it useful to retain the new id for when the html is returned, so you need to arrange for that too.

Comment: Thank you @rivimey. The prefix with the tables for each user works perfectly for my needs. I have max 50 'knowing clients', so this works just fine. :)